# Scanning barcode inputs wrong data

Tags: barcode-scanner, barcode

Using an API to generate a barcode of type UPC-E:

[image: UPCE: 01213113]

I am attempting to scan this barcode using a few different scanner types -

Both the app on my phone, and a Honeywell 3310G hand scanner enter the correct data into the text field:

> 01213113

However, when scanning this barcode on a Windows CE, Motorola MC3190 scan gun, the data the gets entered into the text field is

> 012100001313

Why would different scanners be reading the same barcode differently?

Comment: You’ll have to dig into the manual for the mc3190.  There are many setup functions.  In recent years barcode scanner setup has become a lot easier, but there was a time barcode scanners required much setup.  As I recall this is a convert one type to another, the purpose is uniform length UPC’s for a companies database.  You’ll note that it’s padding 4 zeros in the middle.

Comment: I can look into the manual - the scanner comes the team pre-configured, so I probably wont be able to change to format adjustment. It's not _just_ the padding however, it also appears as if the second to last digit has been removed.

Comment: Yea that’s a convert one bar code type to another within the scanner.  I used to know a lot more about this than I can remember, it’s been many years since the project I had to learn all about barcodes and scanners, however scanners can be setup to do edits and conversions on numbers before sending the data up to the next layer.  Either someone decided they needed that conversion, didn’t think the default value would be bad, didn’t understand what they were doing, or didn’t test with all the barcode types they should have.